# Hibernate updates unchanged child rows on each saveAndFlush

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a database model with a one-to-many relationship in Hiberate, like so

```
class ItemListBean{

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "list", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   List<ItemBean> items;

   ...
}
```

and

```
@Embeddable
class ListItemID{

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "LIST_ID")
   ListItemBean list;

   @Column(name = "VALUE")
   String value;

   ...

}
```

...

```
class ItemBean{

   @EmbeddedId
   ListItemID id;

   //Other item properties, like creation date, created by...
}
```

On each update, the API provided a complete updated list of all the items. It's common for each ItemList to hold thousands of items, and only a few of them change with each given update.

By default, Hibernate updates the properties item in the ItemList on any change, which leads to very poor performance.

```
update LIST_ITEM set CREATE_DATE=?, CREATED_BY=? WHERE ITEM_VALUE=? and LIST_ID=?
```

I would like to update only the parent list's properties, and the items that have changed. Given a complete new list from the API, and the original list from the database. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
    @Autowired
    JpaRepository<ListBean, Long> listDAO;

    @Autowired
    JpaRepository<ListItemBean, ListItemID> itemDAO;
```

...

```
    ListChangeset listDiff = new ListChangeset(updatedList, originalList);

    listDiff.computeItemsToDelete().foreach(li -> itemDAO.delete(li.getID());
    listDiff.computeItemsToAdd().foreach(li -> itemDAO.create(li));

    //Ensure the properties of the unchanged items in the updated list are exactly the same as the properties in the original list
    listDiff.computeRetainedItems().foreach(li -> applyItemProperties(li, originalList));

    return listDAO.saveAndFlush(updatedList);
```

I can see that the change sets are computed correctly and the unmodified ItemBeans are exactly Java-equal... but hibernate still updates every list item on the final saveAndFlush.

How can I stop it from doing that?

====

For completeness, here's ListChangeset

```
  private final Collection<ListItemBean> updatedList;
  private final Collection<ListItemBean> originalList;

  ListChangeset(Collection<ListItemBean> updatedList, Collection<ListItemBean> originalList) {
    this.updatedList = updatedList;
    this.originalList = originalList;
  }

  Collection<ListItemID> computeItemsToDelete(ListBean parent) {
    Collection<ListItemBean> itemsToDelete = removeAll(originalList, updatedList);
    return itemsToDelete.stream().map(li -> new ListItemID(parent, li.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
  }

  Collection<ListItemBean> computeItemsToAdd() {
    return removeAll(updatedList, originalList);
  }

  private static Collection<ListItemBean> removeAll(Collection<ListItemBean> collection, Collection<ListItemBean> remove) {
    List<ListItemBean> itemsToAdd = new ArrayList<>();

    Set<String> removeSet = remove.stream().map(li -> li.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
    for (ListItemBean item : collection){
      if(!removeSet.contains(item.getValue())){
        itemsToAdd.add(item);
      }
    }

    return itemsToAdd;
  }

  public Collection<ListItemBean> computeRetainedItems() {
    List<ListItemBean> retainedItems = new ArrayList<>();

    Set<String> initial = originalList.stream().map(li -> li.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
    for (ListItemBean itemBean : updatedList) {
      if(initial.contains(itemBean.getValue())){
        retainedItems.add(itemBean);
      }
    }

    return retainedItems;
  }
```

Comment: Far too many details are unspecified.  What's a `ListChangeset`? What's `listDAO`?  What's `itemDAO`?  Are the unchanged `ItemBean` entities detached from the persistence unit?  I'm sure other questions would arise.  Construct and present a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the feedback John, I guess I oversimplified in the spirit of trying to ask a good question. I've added the details you mentioned... I don't know exactly what you mean by 'unchanged entities detached from the persistence unit' but all input `ListBean`s contain changed and unchanged items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is due to the fact that `updatedList`'s item collection is a Java collection, whereas `originalList`'s item collection is a [Hibernate collection proxy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching-lazy).

When we `saveAndFlush(updatedList)`, the existing collection proxy is replaced with a Java collection. Hibernate has lost the references to the existing DB objects, so it updates the whole collection in the DB.

The solution here is to instead modify and save the `originalList` and its items - adding and deleting the changed items to the existing collection. This tells Hibernate what the item delta is, and will allow it to write only the changed items to the database.

The working code looks like this

```
// Set the changed properties of the new list in the existing one
originalList.setName(updatedList.getName());
originalList.setDescription(updatedList.getDescription());
```

...

```
// Compute the changed items and set them in the original list
ListChangeset listDiff = new ListChangeset(updatedList, originalList);

originalList.getItems().removeAll(listDiff.computeItemsToDelete());
originalList.getItems().addAll(listDiff.computeItemsToAdd());

return listDAO.saveAndFlush(originalList);
```